# How to get file size in hex format?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, files

What is command to get .img file size in hex format?

Comment: potential X-Y question. What is your target?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't know what "XY problem" you mean, my question was very specific and precise: how to get binary file size in hex format. I need compare file size of existing .img file(specified in hex format) with another .img file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf "%x\n" `stat -c "%s" {filename}`
```

- %x shows it in hex.
- based of "stat" where %s is the number of bytes.

---

Random example from my anime shows:

```
$  printf "%x\n" `stat -c "%s" "[HorribleSubs] Alderamin on the Sky - 13 [1080p].mkv"`
21ed7688
```

Comment: Aww, a few seconds faster than me... There, have an upgoat. - but shouldn't it be `%s` for `stat` to get the file size in bytes? And I recommend adding `\n` to the `printf` so that the next prompt does not get appended to the output line. Like this `printf '%x\n' $(stat -c '%s' .bashrc)`

Comment: +1 to ByteCommander's edit, `"%b"` seems to be returning the wrong value (a 2 byte file should show as '2' in Hex Code, because it's only two bytes).  You may wish to post both commands.  (one for number of blocks, and one for bytes which is probably more what might be desired)

Comment: darn it @ByteCommander

Comment: Should the file name be in double quotes?

Comment: @minto not if you do not have spaces in the name ;-)